# Storing array in yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2

**I have this form in the view:**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/telephone/addnow/" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload your photo:</label><input type="file" name="image" ><br>
    <input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone number" required>
    <br><br>
    <div id="dynamicInput">
        <br><input type="text" name="myinputs[]" placeholder="Secondary Phone #1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></span>
        <br><br>  
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile number" >  <br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="email" name="altemail" placeholder="Alternative Email"><br><BR>
    <input type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name"><br><BR>
    <input type="text" name="company_address" placeholder="Company Address"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="company_phone_primary" placeholder="Company Telephone">    
    <input type="text" name="company_phone_secondary" placeholder="Telephone Secondary "><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="company_email" placeholder="Company Email Address"><br><BR>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><BR><BR>
</form>
```

**allowing the user to insert any number of secondary phones i used this javascript code:**

```
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 10;
    function addInput(divName) {
        if (counter == limit)  {
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
        } else {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = "Seconday Phone # " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myinputs[]' placeholder='Secondary Phone '>";
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            counter++;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**And I have this controller code:**

```
public function actionAddnow()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $add=new telephone();
    $add->Name=$request->post('name');
    $add->Email=$request->post('email');
    $add->Mobile=$request->post('mobile');  
    $add->Address=$request->post('address');
    $add->Telephone=$request->post('telephone');
    $add->altemail=$request->post('altemail');
    $add->company_name=$request->post('company_name');
    $add->company_address=$request->post('company_address');
    $add->company_phone_primary=$request->post('company_phone_primary');
    $add->company_phone_secondary=$request->post('company_phone_secondary');
    $add->company_email=$request->post('company_email');

    $add->save();

    $getlast=Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertId();
    $myinputs=$request->post('myinputs');
    $totalinputs=sizeof('$myinputs');   

    for ($i=0; $i<=$totalinputs; $i++) {
        $inputs=$myinputs[$i];
        $phones=new phone();
        $phones->secondary_phones=$inputs;
        $phones->id=$getlast;
        $phones->save();    
    }
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/telephone/index');     
}
```

but only the first two values of `$myinputs` are inserted in the database.

Comment: have you some validation rules on Phone model?  please show this model

Comment: are you sure this is correct way? `$totalinputs=sizeof('$myinputs');` for getting $toalinputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting variable $myinputs between single quotation marks ('$myinputs') you will convert your variable to string. [sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) is alias for count function, but as you give argument as string you allways get result as 1. After you will loop with condition ($i=0; $i<=$totalinputs; $i++) meaning that cycle will run 2 times when $i is 0 and when $i is 1.

Instead of:

```
$totalinputs=sizeof('$myinputs');
```

**You should use**

```
$totalinputs=sizeof($myinputs);
```

Another error is in your cycle condition.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$totalinputs; $i++)
```

**Should be**

```
for ($i=0; $i<$totalinputs; $i++)
```

Or you could replace for cycle with foreach

```
foreach($myinputs as $inputs)
{
        $phones=new phone();
        $phones->secondary_phones=$inputs;
        $phones->id=$getlast;
        $phones->save();
}
```

On Yii side of improvements

1.For form you could use [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html) widget

```
$form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
        'options' => [
           "role" => "form",
           "enctype"=> "multipart/form-data",
        ], ]); 

echo $form->field($add, 'Name'); 
//etc 
$form->end();
```

2.If you would use ActiveField for creating input fields in view or adding manually field names in format like ModelClassName[ModelFieldName], then you would be able to use Model load for assaign'ing values
Example:

```
$add=new telephone();
if ($add->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
{
   if ($add->save())
   {//saved
   }
   else
   {//error
   }
}
else
{//no post data
}
```

3.For urls its probably not needed to add request baseUrl property. Example in [redirect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail) you can simply use

```
$this->redirect('/telephone/index');
```

4.Using method getLastInsertId() may lead to errors when there are some triggers in database that will create additional rows. So it may be wiser to use:

```
$getlast=$add->id;//assuming model autoincrement field name is "id"
```